# How can I make my ListView row height fit the content inside?

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, android-arrayadapter

Check out my screenshot. Some text gets cut off:

[image]

This is what the row.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Symbol"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#4871A8"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip" android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingLeft="2dip"/>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"     
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4871A8"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:text="15000" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="24sp" android:paddingRight="15dip"/>
   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/changeText" android:text="13.07(+43.08%)" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="right" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="16sp" android:paddingRight="2dp" android:maxLines="3"></TextView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a go to `android:layout_gravity="center"` as parameter for each TextView. You also can use a relative layout and align the objects with `android:layout_centerVertical`

Answer (score 1):

It is looking at the height of your first element @id/nameText and basing the height of the LinearLayout on that... I have tried this in eclipse and seems to look right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/changeText"
        android:text="13.07(+43.08%) please wrap" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/priceText" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/nameText" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="Symbol"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="24sp" android:textColor="#4871A8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/priceText" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4871A8" android:paddingTop="2dip" android:text="15000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="24sp" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameText" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```